# How can I parse multiple lines using ruby_parser?

Tags: ruby, parsing, ruby-parser

I'm trying to use [ruby_parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) to parse some multi-lined Ruby code in a file.

Let's say I want to parse the following code:

```
def foo
  2 + 2
end
```

When I do the following I get an error:

```
RubyParser.new.parse("def foo")
#=> Racc::ParseError: (string):1 :: parse error on value "$end" ($end)
```

because the line does not contain an `end`.

I'm passing lines in one at a time using `File.readlines(file)`.

Ideally I would specify the filename to `RubyParser`, but I can't seem to figure that out, and there's very little documentation.

Comment: [`parser`](https://github.com/whitequark/parser#usage) can do that. (It also has better Ruby syntax support.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass line by line. Pass the whole code at once.

```
RubyParser.new("def foo\n  2 + 2\nend")
```

or

```
RubyParser.new(File.read(file))
```

Comment: Thanks sawa. I thought the issue with passing the whole File in was that it was coming back in a weird format, with \'s at the end of each line and +' s at the beginning of each line. I found out that I had a syntax error in the file I was parsing, which was causing my problems before. Fixed the error, and then `RubyParser.new.parse(File.read(file) works great